# Is it possible to have different starting pages for visitors and logged in users using DokuWiki?

Tags: homepage, dokuwiki

Within the DokuWiki config I can specify a startpage which is opened when my base URL is requested.

I'd like to split my traffic of internal and external users on different startpages.

Is it possible to specify another startpage that is presented for already authenticated users? I could not find such an option within the config page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DocuWiki documentation for startpage](https://www.dokuwiki.org/config:startpage) does not indicate that you can set the value conditionality.

Unless you customize the DocuWiki code, it appears that there is no configuration option for a different start page for logged in users.